# Azure Stream Analytics Fails some times triggering azure function

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-stream-analytics

Azure stream analytics (ASA) receives json pocket from Iothub. I have created azure function to receive data from ASA to Az function. Some times ASA is able to trigger Az function and some times not triggered.

I tried to send same json pocket multiple times to Az function through test query at ASA. But Az function triggers some times and some times not.

I there any specific reason. Do I need to change any settings at ASA side?

Note: Could not find any logs at ASA side and function side also, when function is not triggered

Sample Json pocket:

```
{
"PVersion": "4.0", "PSource": "Controller", "PType": "ControllerData", "serial_no": "X12345", "time_utc": "2020-11-12 10:54:35",
"devices":
[{
    "controller_serial_no": "xxx1234", "controller_profile_id": "1",
    "controller_telemetry":
    [
        {"parameter": "CM Magnitude", "value": "100"},
        {"parameter": "Motor RPM", "value": "11"},
        {"parameter": "Bus Voltage", "value": "234"},
        {"parameter": "Trigger", "value": "1"},
        {"parameter": "Event", "value": "Started Successfully"},
        {"parameter": "Log File", "value": "Telemetry-12Nov2020.txt"}
    ]
  }]
}
```

Azure Function code:

```
 log.LogInformation("Parsing SA JSON pocket");

            string requestBody = await req.ReadAsStringAsync();  //var res= new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync().Result;
            requestBody = requestBody.Trim('[');
            requestBody = requestBody.Trim(']');
            jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonPocket>(requestBody);
```

Comment: There is not enough information here to draw any conclusions. Also what is ASA, Aardvark Sustainability Association? As it stands there could be a range of issues, I suggest going back to first principles and removing all the logic on both sides and test all the moving parts

Comment: ASA stands for Azure Stream Analytics. Generally it should trigger for every time when any data received at ASA right? but it is not?

Comment: what do you mean by -1?

Comment: Hi Eswar, we will need more details to help. Could you share the query that's processing that data? Could you add another output to a storage account to check that all the rows you are expecting are output? And please note that some batching is done between ASA and Function, so 1 event out doesn't translate to 1 call.

Comment: Do you mean, Azure stream analytics will processes data in batching? Not for each request?  I will get JSON pocket on stream analytics, whenever any pocket received on stream analytics It should trigger Azure function and process the data immediately for each json pocket? Is that possible?

Comment: ASA will ingest events as they come, and process them according to the [time windowing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-window-functions) that you define. If you don't define one, then events will processed one at a time from a logical standpoint. But under certain conditions they will be batched out in the output adapter. So you should not count the number of Function evocations, but rather if the final outcome is as expected (what is happening in that Function? You can have 10 events in ASA, 5 function calls out, but still 10 final actions happening).

Comment: Now taking a step back, if you don't need stateful processing (meaning either a time window, or some aggregation), then you're better off using a stateless compute like Azure Functions (so processing one at a time instead) directly. Again, please share the query, and output results in some form of storage to check the actual events out.

Comment: select * into [ComputeAzFunction] from [JSonPocket.json]                                      Result: Showing 0 rows from 'ComputeAzFunction'.

Comment: And have you tried a storage account as an output? For troubleshooting sake?

Comment: My issue got resolved with your suggestions. The problem is with batching . Thanks for your help!